# PCA Scores vs PCA loadings :PCR and PLSR comparison

Tags: r, pca

I am doing a comparison study on PCR and PLSR. 
I have obtained their loadings through package pls in R by using the built in function pcr and plsr.

These were the loadings that I obtained:

[image]

Now. The way that I understand loadings is that they they indicate the amount of variation in a variable that is explained by the component.  Essentially, these loadings represent the correlation between the component and the original variables. Right?

Now, to further assess the components, the plots belowe was constructed to study the component scores. The component scores represents the new variable which is based on the observation’s component loading and the standardised value of the original variable. For PCR the following graph was obtained by plotting the scores.

[image]

and for PLSR:

[image]

I am REALLY struggling as to understand what these plots mean? I would just like to comment on the variables that these two methods deemed most important.

I have been going through tons of questions and answers but can't grasp the just of it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you explain your graphs more? I am not able to understand what scores are you talking about in the graphs that you have plotted.

Comment: @user3667569 `pls.model<-plsr(train[,1]~.,data=train[,-1]……)
pcr.model<-plcr(train[,1]~.,data=train[,-1]……)
pls.model$loadings
pcr.model$loadings
barplot(pls.model$scores[,1], …)
barplot(pcr.model$scores[,1], …) `

Comment: English pls? I did not ask for code.

Comment: I plotted the scores obtained for my first three components